# A non-executing version of :execute

Tags: vim

Is there a command or function like :execute that allows you to send text to the Vim cmdline but that doesn't actually execute it? I want to have the cursor left at the end of the cmdline. I've been going through the help docs for half an hour, can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how that gets triggered. If it's through a mapping, you can simply use `:help :map-expr`:

```
fun! MyText()
    return (localtime() % 2 ? ':echo ' : ':echomsg ')
endfun
:nnoremap <expr> <Leader>e MyText()
```

Else (i.e. through a custom command or by `:autocmd`), you have to use the `feedkeys()` function to insert the typed characters into Vim's input event loop:

```
:command! MyText call feedkeys(MyText(), 'n')
```

You *cannot* just use `:normal`, because that assumes a *full command*, and will abort if it's incomplete.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! The mapping I end up adding was for global searching: `nnoremap <expr> <leader>t ':vim ' . expand("<cword>") . ' *.' . expand('%:e') . ' **/*.' . expand('%:e') 
`